# List is not getting displayed in Sencha touch 2.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, pull-to-refresh

I want to provide a list with pull to refresh functionality.
Below is my code where i have a panel and inside that i have a list.

```
Ext.define('MyProj.common.view.notes.NotesOverlay', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'notesOverlay',

    config: {

        style: 'box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;border-radius: 20px;',
        items: [{
                // Toolbar to be displayed on the Notes overlay
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                ui: 'light',
                docked: 'top',
                //margin:'0 0 20 0',
                //  id:'notesbar',
                items: []
            },
            // List that contains the list of notes 
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                height: 500,
                allowDeselect: true,
                action: 'notesList',
                itemTpl: '{title}',
                data: [{
                        title: 'Item 1'
                    }, {
                        title: 'Item 2'
                    }, {
                        title: 'Item 3'
                    }, {
                        title: 'Item 4'
                    }
                ],

                plugins: [{
                        xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
                        pullRefreshText: 'Pull down to refresh the list'
                    }
                ]


            },

        ]
    }
});
```

I have included the pullRefresh plugin within the list as shown above.
two days back i upgraded project's sencha touch framework to **2.2**, from then on the list disappears.
when i remove the plugin the list is displayed fine.

Please let me know where im going wrong.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Read comments here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.plugin.PullRefresh - looks like there is compatibility issues with PullRefresh plugin and recent ST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sha's comment, the PullRefresh plugin has compatibility issues with ST version.[docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.plugin.PullRefresh](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.plugin.PullRefresh)

Answer (score 1):

You can try add the flex attribute to your list.

But if the list is displayed without the plugin, the case is in plugin